# Github API responding with 'Content is not valid Base64'

Tags: ruby, rest, base64, github-api

I am getting a 'Content is not valid Base64' error when posting a certain, very simple, piece of content to github using the API. The content is

```
 unit = $("<li  class='s   clearfix'></li>");
```

I am using Base64.urlsafe_encode64 to encode the content.

```
content = 'unit = $("<li  class=\'s   clearfix\'></li>")';
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_user}/#{github_repo}/contents/#{path}"
RestClient.put(url, 
                   { 
                      message: "my message", 
                      content: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(content), 
                      encoding:"base64" }.to_json,
                   { 
                      params:{access_token:access_token
                   },accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
   puts response.code
   puts response
}
```

I am getting this reponse:

```
422
{"message":"content is not valid Base64",
 "documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/"}
```

I don't understand how this cannot be valid base64 for github. And it doesn't happen for all submitted data.

```
content='unit = $("<li  class=\'s   clearfix\'></li>")'
Base64.urlsafe_decode64(Base64.urlsafe_encode64(content))==content
=> true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give that a try with `encode64` and `decode64` instead of `urlsafe_decode64` and `urlsafe_encode64`?

Comment: Turns out we have to use Base64.strict_encode64(...) I was snooping around in a github lib and found that:

https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/5323df945ecfd524556888e35d042a96c9055a1c/lib/octokit/client/contents.rb#L76

Comment: Huh, didn't know about that -- thanks for following up and letting me know! + Excellent detective work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the content has to be encoded with **[Base64.strict_encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64)** with complies with RFC 4648. I found the solution here on github: https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/5323df945ecfd524556888e35d042a96c9055a1c/lib/octokit/client/contents.rb#L76

Comment: Good catch, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

When I consider the [Content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/), I dno't see a field 'encoding' when you PUT a message.
I only see it in an answer (like [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21804065/6309)).

If you see the go-github project (in Go, but the idea is the same), you see the structure used for setting up a message: [`RepositoryContentFileOptions`](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/f9fd61547935ca8e568de8ee3a4f1a6a0f94ce32/github/repos_contents.go#L40-L48):

```golang
// RepositoryContentFileOptions specifies optional parameters for CreateFile, UpdateFile, and DeleteFile.
type RepositoryContentFileOptions struct {
  Message *string `json:"message,omitempty"`
  Content []byte `json:"content,omitempty"`
  SHA *string `json:"sha,omitempty"`
  Branch *string `json:"branch,omitempty"`
  Author *CommitAuthor `json:"author,omitempty"`
  Committer *CommitAuthor `json:"committer,omitempty"`
}
```

The [tests don't encode anything](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/f9fd61547935ca8e568de8ee3a4f1a6a0f94ce32/github/repos_contents_test.go#L108-L144):

```golang
message := "m"
content := []byte("c")
repositoryContentsOptions := &RepositoryContentFileOptions{
  Message: &message,
  Content: content,
  Committer: &CommitAuthor{Name: String("n"), Email: String("e")},
}
```

In your case (ruby), `content` should be enough.

Comment: Git actually ignores the encoding parameter, so you are right. But my problem was that I wasn't using the correct the base64 encoding, apparently there are differences. See my answer.